# How to modify existing word docx file using phpdocx

Tags: php, pdf-generation, docx

I would like to modify my existing word ( docx ) file using phpdocx. How it is possible to set borders on my current word file Using php docx ?

Comment: could you please report the correct answer or add more information if this didn't solve you problem?

Answer (score 0):

If with "borders" you mean  margins just use the function:

```
         modifyPageLayout ($paperType ,array('marginTop' => '3',
                                             'marginRight' => '2',
                                             'marginBottom' => '3',
                                             'marginLeft' => '2'));
```

the integer gives the size in twentieths of a point!